# How to reach my main form controlls from my UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have Balloon `user control` that opens in the tray when my application is minimyze.
So i created simple `Button` on this Balloon:

```
public partial class ApplicationBalloon : UserControl
{ 
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

When this event is fired i want to click on specific button in my main form so i can i reach my main form controlls from this `UserControl` ?

EDIT

In my main form after the c'tor:

```
    applicationBalloon = new ApplicationBalloon();
    applicationBalloon.BalloonClicked += applicationBalloon_BalloonClicked;
```

And in my `User Control`:

```
public partial class ApplicationBalloon : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> BalloonClicked;
    public ApplicationBalloon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BalloonClicked != null)
            BalloonClicked(sender, e);
    }
}
```

The `btnStart_Click` is after my application is running and allthough `BalloonClicked` is still `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event to your balloon class, handle the click in your balloon class and pass the arguments up to whoever attaches to your event.

In your balloon class:

```
public partial class ApplicationBalloon : UserControl
{ 
    public event EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> BalloonClicked;

    private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BalloonClicked != null)
            BalloonClicked(sender, e);
    }
}
```

You can now add a handler to your main form attached to BalloonClicked.

Comment: After subscride to BalloonClicked in my main form (after applicationBalloon = new ApplicationBalloon();) BalloonClicked is still null.

Comment: Is it possible that you are instantiating two instances of Balloon (maybe one in XAML and another from code?) You can check by putting a breakpoint in your Balloon constructor and make sure it gets hit only once. (Also, make sure your handler subscription gets called before you are checking BalloonClicked for null.)

Comment: @mark yer Could you show your definition of applicationBalloon_BalloonClicked?

Answer (score 0):

Just access it with:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow
```

And cast it to whatever your main window type is.